# Objective-C: Recognize swipe gestures when fingers still on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I have Image View on my screen and I want detect, when user swipe on this image left-to-right and right-to-left non stop. And his fingers still on the screen, when he do it. Every swipe I want added to my `swipeCount`variable.
I tried this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.startPosition = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];
    if (self.startPosition.x != endPosition.x || self.startPosition.y != endPosition.y) {
        self.swipeCount++;
        self.labelSwipeCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.swipeCount];
    }
}
```

But touchesEnded doesn't work if user doesn't go beyond the image. How can I realize my idea?